# how to call external php in iframe using fancybox

Tags: php, fancybox

i cant open a iframe using fancybox which is calling the external php script file
and this is the anchor tag i used to call
`<a id="iframe" href="gallery.php" >Gallery</a>`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#iframe" ).fancybox({
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : 885,
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        'href'              : "gallery.php"
    });
```

});

the gallery.php file is on same folder
**also the calling page is also on php**

Comment: it works the same as with any other file as well, so I remove the PHP tag as this has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: In this case the `href` option is useless since you are already binding fancybox to an anchor with the `href` attribute. Use `href` option when you bind a `click` event instead to the element and that event triggers fancybox.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not. In you case you can also simply use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` and then use `$` inside that function.

Comment: @SudhanshuSaxena And what did you see when you click on anchor tag?? Gallary.php or empty fancybox??

Comment: @phazorRise nothing happens...but when i click to open in new tab oe window then it simply runs my gallery.php file flawless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this list and make sure you have done each one:

- Included the jquery library and ensured it is including it correctly (this can be done by using "firebug" and the "net" tab).
- Included both the fancybox css and javascript library, again checking they have both been included successfully.
- Try using an exact path e.g http://www.test.com/gallery.php

Here is an example of what your html file should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.test.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.test.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.test.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#iframe" ).fancybox({
            'width'             : '75%',
            'height'            : 885,
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'href'              : "http://www.test.com/gallery.php"
        });
    });
</script>

<a id="iframe">Gallery</a>
```

If you go through these steps and ensure your html looks exactly as I have said, you should have no issues.

Comment: thank you so much...it works...i have some conflicting queries which prevents to load iframe...thanx a lot @Adam